# I have staging table and need a dimension table. I also need to add a surrogate key. I am using SSIS. How do I go about it?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

My staging table is `[sabyastaging].[dbo].[CustomerSTG]` has the following fields : `[customer#],[cust-name],[address],[telephone#]`

I need a dimension table (`Customer`) which as the fields : `[customer#],[address]` and `[telephone#]`.

Also I need a surrogate key. I am using management studio and SSIS. How do I do it?

Help shall be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please consider posting a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

First create the target dimension table:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustomerSK int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerNumber int,
    CustomerName VARCHAR(200),
    CustomerAddress VARCHAR(200)
```

The SK is created with an auto-incrementing column, which doubles as the primary key for the table.  The dimension and fact tables in your warehouse should not have any foreign key references, especially back to a staging area.  Also, I would avoid characters like "#" in your tables or column names, and I would try to spell out into human-readable form all of your names - after all, these tables are probably end-user facing and need to be easy to understand.

Fire up Visual Studio and create the SSIS project.  Create connections for your source and target tables.  Drag the "Data Flow" task onto the canvas, and double click it.  Drag over an OLE DB source connector, and provide connection information for your source database and your staging table. Do the same for your target dimension table.

Click and drag a data flow connector from source to target - you'll have a green line going from your source connection to your target connection.  Double click on the target connection, and you'll see a way you can map your input columns to your output columns - just click and drag from source to target.

Hit F5 and it should run.

Comment: Good answer! Also if you are using an up to date version of SQL Server you can use a sequence which has advantages of speed, and also you can know the value prior to inserting the dim record if required.